# How do I create an array/matrix from a set of data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question has probably been asked before and I have found numerous ways of solving it, but none seems to be working for my problem.

The data sheet i am trying to read looks like this:

```
-6   -6 -3.74767E-003 -3.74767E-003  5.30000E-003  1.87773E+001  1.87008E+001  1.87711E+001  1.86925E+001     -0.039128%/n
-6   -5 -3.74767E-003 -3.12305E-003  4.87837E-003  1.87773E+001  1.55840E+001  1.87728E+001  1.55787E+001     -0.028419%/n
```

(Note the % at the last line I blame it to be cause the issues.) I have tried split but it always comes down to variations of `'list' object has no attribute 'split'` error message.

I want to create a matrix numpy array in the following way:

```
  (x1 y1 0 0
   0  0 x1 y1
   :
   :
   :
   xn yn 0 0 
   0  0  xn yn)
```

I attached some of the code I tried for this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    d=reader()
    XY_real=projected(d)    
    matrix=matrix_f(d)

def reader():    
    #loads the values into d:
    d=np.genfromtxt("Eris-106-Cam1.txt",delimiter='',dtype=float)
    #print(d[0][0])
    return d

def projected(d):

    #Sets XY_real as value. 
    Dummy_array = np.asarray(d)

    #Load x/y values:
    i=1
    X_real_array0=np.array([Dummy_array[0][7]])
    Y_real_array0=np.array([Dummy_array[0][8]])
    XY_real_array=np.empty([1,1])

    while i<169:

        x_real=float(Dummy_array[i][7])
        y_real=float(Dummy_array[i][8])

        #XY Array:
        X_real=np.array([x_real])
        XY_real_array=np.append([[XY_real_array]],[[X_real]])
        Y_real=np.array([y_real])
        XY_real_array=np.append([[XY_real_array]],[[Y_real]])

        i=i+1

    print type(XY_real_array)

def matrix_f(d):

    Dummy_array = np.asarray(d)
    x0=float(Dummy_array[0][2])
    y0=float(Dummy_array[0][3])

    matrix=np.array([[x0,y0,0,0],[0,0,x0,y0]])
    i=0
    while i < 169:

        x=float(Dummy_array[i][2])
        y=float(Dummy_array[i][3])

        matrix0=np.array([[x,y,0,0],[0,0,x,y]])
        matrix=np.append([[matrix]],[[matrix0]])
        i=i+1

    print(matrix)

main()
```

This will yield the needed matrix:

```
[-0.00374767 -0.00374767  0.         ...,  0.          0.00374767
```

0.00374767]

which is: `[x_i y_i 0 0 ... 0 0 x_i y_i]`

Now if I am trying to call one of the x_i with:

```
print(matrix[0][0])

  *File "/home/sebo/Documents/reader.py", line 72, in matrix_f
    print(matrix[0][0])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.*
```

--> This goes on when I am trying to find a pseudo inverse. I assume the problem is originating from the way I load the numbers, because when I am printing the matrix you can see that the values are not separated by comma! This is because I think they are stored as list inside the array (?) I might be completely, but please help me :D

Comment: could you maybe rephrase this better, to me it seems a little unclear what exactly you're trying to do (and why you want a 2D array)

Comment: Hello Thanks,  I am trying to get the x and y values from a Zemax file. The Zemax file looks like what I posted. The actual problem is that I never get the numbers that a stored in my data file as a float, it always returns lists (with only the number in it, but the numpy routines that Im trying to use are accepting that, they need the plain number)

Comment: Hello, I completely changed the layout of my question, I am sorry if I messed with you all, but thats my problem as it is in front of me

Comment: I solved my problem finally. No Idea why it works now and not before but thanks anyways!

Comment: Index arrays with `data[0, 0]`, not `data[0][0]`.  The latter if for nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your input with my code, basic string manipulation concepts and it worked. The code along with the input and output are attached.

```
input = raw_input()
numbers=input.split()
nos=list()

for i in numbers:
    nos.append(float(i))

for i in nos:
    print i
```

The input is

> -6 -6 -3.74767E-003 -3.74767E-003 5.30000E-003 1.87773E+001 1.87008E+001 1.87711E+001 1.86925E+001 -0.039128 -6 -5 -3.74767E-003 -3.12305E-003 4.87837E-003 1.87773E+001 1.55840E+001 1.87728E+001 1.55787E+001 -0.028419

And the output obtained is

> -6.0
>       -6.0
>       -0.00374767
>       -0.00374767
>       0.0053
>       18.7773
>       18.7008
>       18.7711
>       18.6925
>       -0.039128
>       -6.0
>       -5.0
>       -0.00374767
>       -0.00312305
>       0.00487837
>       18.7773
>       15.584
>       18.7728
>       15.5787
>       -0.028419

The output is in different lines.
Hope that's it! :)

Comment: Hey thanks, However when Im trying to than convert it as an np.array I still have the same problem.... Inside the array values are still stored as list not as float... :(   I used np.array & np.asarray to do that

Comment: Hello, I completely changed the layout of my question, I am sorry if I messed with you all, but thats my problem as it is in front of me